# Sort Mismatch in Model

Tags: z3

I have analyzed a formula in QF_AUFLIA with z3. The result was `sat`. The model returned by `(get-model)` contained the following lines:

```
  (define-fun PCsc5_ () Int
    (ite (= 2 false) 23 33)
```

According to my understanding of the SMTLIBv2 language, this statement is malformed. `=` should only be applied to arguments of the same sort. However, `2` has sort `Int` and `false` has sort `Bool`.

When I feed back just these two lines to z3, it agrees with me by saying:

```
invalid function application, sort mismatch on argument at position 2
```

Is this a bug?

If not, how am I supposed to interpret `(= 2 false)`?

Comment: Yes, this seems to be a bug in the model construction. Could you send us the formula that generates this bogus model? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was due to a type error in the input. Z3 3.2 misses some type errors in macro applications. This problem was fixed. The next release will correctly report the type error (aka sort mismatch). Here is a minimal example that exposes the problem:

```
(set-option :produce-models true)
(declare-fun q (Int) Bool)
;; p1 is a macro
(define-fun p1 ((z Int) (y Int)) Bool
  (ite (q y) (= z 0) (= z 1)))
(declare-const a Int)
(declare-const b Bool)
(assert (p1 a b)) ;; << TYPE ERROR: b must be an Int
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```